# How to control a loop using a button?

Tags: java, loops, user-interface, iteration

I am a beginner in java, I want to know is there any possible way to control a loop by clicking a button? I am creating a GUI, and it's supposed to run 10 times in the loop. Is there a way that I could have a button on the screen so that when the user presses, then it goes to the next iteration? Because currently everything just runs and executes once.

Comment: Juat be careful when using loops within the context of the GUI, as most UI's are single threaded, meaning a loop could prevent them from being updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your java class, you should define an attribute and each time you click on the button you add 1 to this attribute and do the action.

define an attribute in your class;

```
public int i = 0;
```

and create a button to be clicked on:

```
private void clickMeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    // code your action here:
    this.i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have the loop wait for the button click, and then once it loops 10 times break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javaFX it's gonna replace javaswing very soon anyways plus it's cooler.

```
import javafx.scene.control.button

Button button = new Button("control");
       int i = 0;
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        i++;
        label.setText("i increased");
     }
});
```